# Android Outofmemory exception with bitmaps

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-bitmap

I have a function that take a bitmap, two colors and return a BitmapDrawable :

```
// Theme function
    static public BitmapDrawable pFilter(Bitmap bitmap, int backgroundColor, int foregroundColor)
{

    Bitmap bitmapCopy = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), null, true);

    int[] pixels = new int[bitmapCopy.getByteCount()]; 

    bitmapCopy.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmapCopy.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmapCopy.getWidth(), bitmapCopy.getHeight());

    // Call native function

    bitmapCopy.setPixels(pixels, 0, bitmapCopy.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmapCopy.getWidth(), bitmapCopy.getHeight());

    BitmapDrawable finalDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(Application.getAppContext().getResources(), bitmapCopy);

    return finalDrawable;
}

// Custom Imageview
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView 
{

private BitmapDrawable sourceImage;

private CustomTheme theme;

// [...]

private void refreshImageView()
{

  super.setImageDrawable(theme.pFilter(sourceImage.getBitmap(), theme.backgroundColor, theme.foregroundColor));

}
```

My problem is that after about 80 calls to this function (with 10px*10px bitmaps), I get a OutOfMemory exception on this line :

```
int[] pixels = new int[bitmapCopy.getByteCount()];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in my JNI call, not in Android :

```
(*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, pixels, nativePixels, JNI_COMMIT);
```

> JNI_COMMIT : copy back the content but do not free the elems buffer

The solution is to use 0 instead of JNI_COMMIT :

```
(*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, pixels, nativePixels, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

after calling the pFilter(??);  call bitmap.recycle(); on the orignal bitmap

Comment: I get an error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot draw recycled bitmaps

Comment: the original bitmap is still displayed on the imageView  right? try to replace it with something else before calling recycle.

Comment: Yes, take a look of my code : BitmapDrawable finalDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(Application.getAppContext().getResources(), bitmapCopy);

Comment: My theme class don't know my ImageView... So, when and where must I call the recyle ? In the CustomImgeView's finalize ?

Comment: Bitmap oldBitmap = sourceImage.getBitmap();
sourceImage=theme.pFilter(oldBitmap);
super.setImageDrawable(theme.pFilter(oldBitmap, theme.backgroundColor, theme.foregroundColor));
  postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   
   @Override
   public void run() {
    oldBitmap.recycle();
   }
  }, 20);

Comment: The sourceBitmap is never cleared ? And why are you using a delay ?

Comment: Recycle do nothing, System.gc too. I've also try to use WeakReference : do nothing. In the DDMS view I can see my object, never cleared...